# PostgreSQL - a query counting the actions a user made per day

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table with the following fields: userId, actionDate, actionType
I'd like to create a query to result in a list of actions each user performed each day

I've tried this query:

```
select userId, actionDate, count(*) from userActionList group by userId, actionDate;
```

**the problem:** is my actionDate is a date time field and I get results based on the both date & time and I want it to group only based on date (disregarding the time)

Comment: `date_trunc( 'day' , actionDate )` it is in the manual.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the modification of your query you seem to be asking for:

```
select userId, date_trunc('day', actionDate) as actionDate, count(*)
from userActionList
group by userId, date_trunc('day', actionDate);
```

This counts the activities.  If you want a list:

```
select userId, date_trunc('day', actionDate) as actionDate, count(*),
       string_agg(actionType, '; ' order by actionDate) as actions
from userActionList
group by userId, date_trunc('day', actionDate);
```